Bandwidth measured is two orders of magntiude less than expected TIA circuit
I have the following photodiode schematic, all soldered onto a small PCB. The first stage is a TIA, and the second stage filters out high frequency signals. The calculated bandwidth of the circuit based on the first op amp GBP (1.6 GHz) should be around 2 MHz (using GBP = 2piRCf^2). The bandwidth I measured was around 60 kHz, from which I expected to be due to around 1 pF of parasitic capacitance in parallel with the 10 M resistor (using f = 1/2piRC). However, after swapping out the resistor with a 100 k resistor, I see the same bandwidth, when I expect it to be 100x higher. Thus I suspect this can't be the problem. What could be the problem here?


EDIT: Two graphs below demonstrating the bandwidth for 100k and 10k feedback resistor. Curiously the 10k results in a lower bandwidth by around 1 order of magnitude, suggesting that the bandwidth is proportional to the resistance rather than inversely. (Ignore the absolue magnitude of the pp and rms voltages, because I aligned the optics a bit differently in the two setups so the magnitudes may be off).



How exactly did you measure the bandwidth?

I've put two graphs in my response above. On second look the actual "bandwidth" is probably a little bit larger than 60kHz but the response with respect to the feedback resistor is still very unusual (the bandwidth is lower for a lower resistance).

How are you measuring the BW? Can you validate that the rest of your test setup is not causing the BW limitation? Eg inject an electrical signal directly to the input of IC1 through a moderately high resistor (eg 100k).


The calculated bandwidth of the circuit based on the first op amp GBP (1.6 GHz) should be around 2 MHz (using GBP = 2piRCf^2). The bandwidth I measured was around 60 kHz, from which I expected to be due to around 1 pF of parasitic capacitance in parallel with the 10 M resistor (using f = 1/2piRC).

Photodiode capacitance: Cd ~ 8.5pF (@ 118V reverse bias)
Op amp common mode input capacitance: Ccm = 4.5pF
Op amp differential mode input capacitance: Cdm = 0.7pF
Total: Ct = 13.7pF
With a feedback resistor Rf = 10 MOhm and an op amp GBW = 1600MHz the theoretical 3dB bandwidth would be approximately:
f(3dB) ~ SQR (GBW / (2 x Pi x Ct x Rf)) = 1.363MHz
For a maximally flat (Butterworth, 2nd order, Q = 0.707) frequency response the feedback pole fp would be placed 2 x Q lower in frequency:
fp = f(3dB) / 2 x Q = 964kHz
The neccessary compensation capacitor across Rf would have to be
Cf = 1 / (2 x Pi x Rf x fp) = 0.0165pF
which is completely unrealistic. Assuming a best case parasitic capacitance of 0.2pF, the feedback pole is de facto lowered by a factor of 12 to 79.6 kHz.
To circumvent this involuntary bandwidth limitation, a T-type feedback network instead of single resistor feedback would lower the resistor values considerably while keeping gain and bandwidth high.

This is a great answer. You can also improve the bandwidth with more careful guarding between the pads of the feedback resistor at the same potential as the opamp virtual ground.

Thank you! Perhaps I'm not understanding the answer, but I would think that if I was bandwidth limited by the capacitance across Rf, then my bandwidth should increase if I reduce Rf. But I didn't see this happen when I changed the resistance from 10 M to 100 k, so I'm confused as to what the reason may be.

I also added two graphs in my original post that might provide some additional info

@CollinFan - With 10M gain you are certainly limited in bandwidth. Another bandwidth limiting factor would be the impedance of the current source (PD) itself. With 100k gain the bandwidth definitely needs to be larger (with ~0.16pF compensation cap) than shown. Be aware that the OPA651 is a decompensated op amp (not unity gain stable) and the compensation capacitor across the feedback resistor has a limited value range. The bandwidth measurements you made don't make much sense. What measurement setup are you using?

@LukeGary - Yes, guarding would be indeed indicated to avoid leakage with very high impedance sources. A ground trace directly below the ceramic package of the resistor helps reducing the parasitic capacitance by shunting the electrical field between the resistor caps to ground.
